# What is the name and part number of this piece? Part of a crane, long and thin without studs

Tags: part-identification

The piece is used to build a crane as found in [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Am-Ls-FvFvA)

[image: long and thin without studs]

Answer (score 8):

At the very beginning of the video part list can be seen, but since it is computer generated it is rather confusing at the first sight. If you check few moments later in the the video you'll notice these are [Technic, Axle 3L](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4519#T=C) (4519) in Yellow:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. Was fooled by the part list picture.